# How can I import passwords from Chrome into Firefox in Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, kubuntu, import, password-management

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/import-passwords-from-chrome-to-firefox says one should use, in Firefox on Windows 10:

[image]

However I don't see the `Saved Passwords` option in Firefox in Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS:

[image]

I use Firefox 99.0 x64 in Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Export the Chrome passwords to a CSV file, by going to `chrome://settings/passwords?search=passw`, clicking on these vertical dots

[image]

[image]

Step 2: In Firefox, enable password imports by going to about:config and setting `signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled` to `true`:

[image]

Step 3: In Firefox, import passwords from the CSV file:

[image]

[image]

Reddit user [bwat47](https://www.reddit.com/user/bwat47) [pointed me](https://redd.it/uh8aim) to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another not-quite-answer would be to export your passwords and import them into a password manager like KeepassX.

This lets you use a plugin to safely use one password (to unlock the password manager: since it remembers the PWs for you, passwords like `mLjf45&*(R984msfe089` are not too painful.

You do need to figure out how/where to store your encrypted database of passwords.  If you only use one PC, then great, no problem. But, if you only use one computer on the internet you probably are still using a POTS dial-up modem. Apps are available for Android and iOS too.

Some people worry about keeping it on Dropbox, GDrive, etc. as snapshots are archived (I think you can turn this off) and it is not 100% under your control. I would argue that a USB drive is even less secure, given the number I have lost over the years (you haven't seen a yellow thumbdrive laying around???). Just be sure you have a back up stored off-line someplace safe just in case you cannot get to the service.

Slightly off-topic, but perhaps a better practice.